# Missing Quick-Fix solutions in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

So I'm using Eclipse for Java development but I'm getting annoyed that the "Quick-Fix" context menu is incomplete. In the Eclipse documentation, there's a full list of all the quick fixes for different common problems. If I press Ctrl+1 over an error, I get an incomplete list of "Quick-Fixes".
For Example, I know for a fact that "Create setters and getters" is a quick fix for instances where private variables in a class are never called.
However, this is not an option when I use the Quick Fix command for the item.
Also, quick fixes are NOT showing up in the context menu for items marked with errors. I have confirmed in Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist: that "Insert common prefixes automatically" is checked to True.
Is there possibly a problem with the JRE? (I DID have an issue earlier where the context menu wouldn't appear at all because eclipse couldn't find the .rt file. I had to decompress it and point eclipse to the folder containing the JRE before it would show anything.)
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use the JDK instead of the JRE ?! This is not a possible solution, but it worth to try!

Comment: No, I have the JDK installed. The JRE is just where the documentation and everything was. Thanks though.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of what this looks like? Also, take a look at your Eclipse error log and paste any relevant errors.

Comment: It generally helps to add some details. What version of Eclipse? What platform are you on? Add anything else you think is relevant or unusual about your system.  Then  create a simple demo of the problem. Create a class put a private variable in the class and make sure the problem happens. And then I'm with Andrew, take a screenshot of that  entire class demo and post it so we can see it. You should be seeing that quick fix so something is wrong.

Comment: I'm on windows 7, 64 bit. I'm using Java 7 JDK and JRE, both update in the past 24 hours. I'm using Eclipse v.3.3.2. (Screenshot added)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I feel so stupid but found the issue. Somehow, I installed the 2008, 3.3.2 version of Eclipse. Stumps me how it happened by it did. Lol. So After uninstalling and reinstalling the newest version of Eclipse, everything worked as expected. Thanks.